# Puppet 4: how to add calling class variables to scope of a defined type

Tags: puppet

In Puppet 3 and prior, templates in defines inherited scope from their calling class the same way native defined types do, so if I had a file resource with a template source created by a define, that template could make use of variables set in the calling class no matter which class called the define.

In Puppet 4 (also tested with Puppet 3.8 future parser), that appears to no longer be the case, and it is causing breakage that is hard to even measure in my environment, which has relied on this behavior for tens of thousands of lines of code. Is there any way at all to get this back?  After looking into it, even converting the defines into native types doesn't solve the problem, as they rely on the ability to gather server-side information about what templates are available in different modules via custom functions, and everything in a native resource type appears to happen on the client.

Is this fixable, or do I attempt to wait for Puppet 5?

Edit: Don't get too caught up in the word 'scope' here -- I need any way to pass all class variables to a define and unpack them there so that they are available to templates, or a way to have a native type see what files are inside specified modules on the puppetmaster.  I will accept any bizarre, obscure message passing option as long as it has this result, because the classes *do not know* where the templates are -- only the define does, because it's making use of the helper functions that scan the filesystem on the server.

Edit 2: To prove this works as expected in Puppet 3.8.5, use the following:

modules/so1/manifests/autotemplate.pp:

```
# Minimal define example for debugging
define so1::autotemplate (
    $ensure = 'present',
    $module = $caller_module_name,
) {
    $realtemplate = "${module}${title}"

    file { $title :
        ensure  => $ensure,
        owner   => 'root', group => 'root', mode => '0600',
        content => template($realtemplate),
    }
}
```

in modules/so2/manifests/example.pp:

```
# Example class calling so1::autotemplate
class so2::example (
    $value = 'is the expected value'
) {
    so1::autotemplate { '/tmp/qwerasdf': }
}
```

in modules/so2/templates/tmp/qwerasdf:

```
Expected value: <%= @value %>
```

In Puppet 3.8.5 with future parser off, this results in /tmp/qwerasdf being generated on the system with the contents:

```
Expected value: is the expected value
```

In Puppet 3.8.5. with `parser = future` in environment.conf (and also Puppet 4.x, though I tested for this example specifically on a 3.8.5 future parser environment), this results in the file being create with the contents:

```
Expected value:
```

Edit 3: two-word touch-up for precision

Comment: One cannot avoid focusing on "scope" when that's not only the word you use, but the *right* word for the concept you're discussing.  Your edit therefore seems to be trying to change the question to ask something substantially different than it did before. At the risk of sounding self-serving, you should not do that after having received an answer.

Comment: The question is the one in the title -- how do I add all calling class variables to the scope of a defined type.  The rest is just background -- in Puppet 3 this happened automatically, all the way up through 3.8.5.  I don't need it to be automatic in Puppet 4 -- I just need it to be _possible_.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is still what I wrote (as updated).  Defined types in Puppet 3 *never* got variables from the using classes' scopes.  Templates did, but that was a bug, albeit one fixed only in Puppet 4 and when the future parser is enabled in Puppet 3.  You can communicate data from the calling class to a defined type via the defined type's parameters, and a template can access data from foreign scopes via its `scope` object.  There's no reason to think that this will change in Puppet 5.

Answer (score 1):

> In Puppet 3 and prior, defines inherited scope from their calling class the same way native defined types do, so if I had a file resource with a template source created by a define, that template could make use of variables set in the calling class no matter which class called the define.

What you're describing is Puppet's old dynamic scoping.  The change in scoping rules was one of the major changes in Puppet 3.0; it is not new in Puppet 4.  There was, however, [a **bug**](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1220) in Puppet 3 that templates still used dynamic scope.  That was fixed in Puppet 3.5, but only prospectively -- that is, when the future parser is enabled.  Defined types themselves went through the scoping change in Puppet 3.0.0, along with everything else.   The scope changes were a big deal (and Puppet devoted considerable effort to alerting users to them) when they first went into place, but nowadays there's no big deal here.

> it is causing breakage that is hard to even measure in my environment, which has relied on this behavior for tens of thousands of lines of code.

I'm sorry you're having that experience.

> Is there any way at all to get this back?

No.  Puppet scoping rules do not work the way you want them to do.  That they did work that way in templates (but not most other places) in Puppet 3 was and still is contrary to Puppet's documentation, and never intentional.

> Is this fixable, or do I attempt to wait for Puppet 5?

There is no way to get dynamic variable scoping in templates or elsewhere in Puppet 4, and I have no reason to think that there will be one in Puppet 5.

If you need a template to expand host variables from the scope of a particular class, then you can get that by evaluating the template in the scope of that class.  Alternatively, an ERB template can obtain variables from (specific) other scopes [by means of the `scope` object](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/lang_template_erb.html#accessing-puppet-variables).  On the other hand, if you want to expand the template in the scope of a defined type, then you could consider passing the needed variables as parameters of that type.

There may be other ways to address your problem, but I'd need more details to make any other suggestions.  (And that would constitute a separate question if you choose to ask it here on SO.)

Comment: Agree that it is doubtful this will reappear in Puppet 5.

Comment: See my update.  Don't get too caught up in the mechanics of scoping -- the question is really about how to package up every variable in a class so that they can show up in the scope of the define.  I don't care if it happens by scope, by obscure functions, by custom ruby code I hide on the server somewhere, as long as a class can say 'deal with this file' in one line and have the logic from the define work.

Comment: Also, as an aside, this code *absolutely works* on Puppet 3.8.5 without future parser enabled.  It breaks instantly as soon as future parser is enabled, or on Puppet 4.8.2

Comment: @Zed, if you think my comments do not apply to your code, then I'm inclined to think that what your code does is not well characterized by the question.  Your edit also leads me in that direction.  If indeed your question is about something different from scope, then I suggest that when you try posing it again, you accompany it with a [mcve] to help clarify what you really want to know.

Comment: @Zed, you are right, the buggy behavior is present in all versions of Puppet 3 when the future parser is not enabled.  The fix applies only when the future parser is enabled.  I have updated my answer in that regard.  It was still never intended that templates should use dynamic scope in Puppet 3, and they *don't* when the future parser is enabled.  This general kind of thing -- helping you prepare for changes between major versions -- is one of the purposes of the future parser.

Comment: I am getting the sense that you are simply refusing to believe what I am telling you in the problem description, but you can replicate it at will with the minimal examples I just posted.  I need a way for that "autotemplate" define to pick up any variables in the example.pp without them being explicitly enumerated, because it could be used in any class in any module with arbitrary parameters.

Comment: Okay, so now we've established it's a change from Puppet 3.8.5 -- how do I pass all variables from a class to that define, e.g. as a hash, or cause the define to inherit the calling class?

Comment: @Zed, again, the calling class can pass data -- of any type -- to a defined type via that type's parameters.  In particular, it could pass a hash if that's what you wish.  The Puppet language does not have a built-in mechanism for automatically constructing a hash containing all the variables in scope at any given point, but certainly any class is capable of manually populating a hash with the (other) variables in its local scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136794/discussion-between-zed-and-john-bollinger).